# MS SQL Перенос атрибутов из одной таблицы в другую. Копирование данных из одной таблицы в другую

Tags: sql-server, запрос, select, копирование

)
Вводные:
-Есть таблица "Table_1" t1 с атрибутами "ID", "Comment"
-Есть таблица "Table_2" t2 с атрибутами "ID", "Name", "Explanation"

t1.ID = t2.ID
t1.ID - Уникальное поле в таблице (Ключ)
t2.ID - Не уникальное поле, ID могут повторятся.

Необходимо t2.Name и t2.Explanation записывать в t1.Comment следующим образом:
"Name" : "Explanation";"Name" : "Explanation"

Получается необходимо обработать все строки из t2 записав в таком формате в t1 через точку с запятой, разделяя "Name" и "Explanation" вот так: " : "

Необходимо это делать каждый час, получается поле "Comment" необходимо не перезаписывать, а добавлять в него данные по формату выше.
Так же после того, как из таблицы t2 атрибуты из строки были добавлены в t1. - эту строку необходимо в t2 удалить. Чтобы при следующей итерации (через час) - она опять не записалась в таблицу t1.
БД MS SQL.
Очень вас прошу, помогите пожалуйста с решением данной задачи. Если вводных не хватает - говорите - я их добавлю.
Заранее спасибо вам большущие!!!)
Обнял.

Comment: какой SQL? на My - решается в лоб через переменную, на PG - в лоб через подзапрос и функцию агрегации, на MS подозреваю что так же как в PG

[Вотъ для MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/functions/aggregate/array-agg)

Comment: А вот [так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/how-do-i-update-from-a-select-in-sql-server) можно записать сам запрос (в подзапросе - агрегация из первого комментария)

Comment: Но таким образом
UPDATE
    Table_A
SET
    Table_A.col1 = Table_B.col1,
    Table_A.col2 = Table_B.col2
FROM
    Some_Table AS Table_A
    INNER JOIN Other_Table AS Table_B
        ON Table_A.id = Table_B.id
WHERE
    Table_A.col3 = 'cool'

Колонки будут перезаписываться же каждый раз, как запускаем данный запрос, разве нет?
А удаление строк из t2 как то можно впихнуть туда?

Comment: и на кой эта борода нужна?

Answer (score 2):

Не хочу вас расстраивать, но для вашей задаче лучше подойдёт триггер или вьюха...
При этом не раз в час будет обновляться, а будет сохраняться консистентность постоянно.
Вод код:

```
-- Всё делаем во временной БД
USE tempdb
GO
-- Чистим БД, чтобы при повторных запусках не ругалось
IF OBJECT_ID('V_Table1_V1') IS NOT NULL DROP VIEW V_Table1_V1
IF OBJECT_ID('V_Table1_V2') IS NOT NULL DROP VIEW V_Table1_V2
IF OBJECT_ID('T_IUD_Table2') IS NOT NULL DROP TRIGGER T_IUD_Table2
IF OBJECT_ID('Table2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE Table2
IF OBJECT_ID('Table1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE Table1
GO
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Comment VARCHAR(1024)
  )
CREATE TABLE Table2  (
    Id INT REFERENCES Table1 (Id),
    Name VARCHAR(1024),
    Explanation VARCHAR(1024),
  )
GO
--Собственно сам триггер:
CREATE TRIGGER T_IUD_Table2
ON Table2
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
UPDATE T1
SET Comment = STUFF(
  (SELECT(
    SELECT CONCAT('; "',Name,'" : "',Explanation,'"') 
    FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.Id = T1.Id
    ORDER BY Name, Explanation FOR XML PATH('')
  )), 1, 2, '')
FROM Table1 T1
WHERE T1.Id 
  IN (SELECT Id FROM INSERTED UNION SELECT Id FROM DELETED)
GO

INSERT Table1 VALUES(1,NULL),(2,'')

-- Тестим INSERT
INSERT Table2 VALUES
  (1,'Мама','Мыла'),(1,'Раму','Рама'),(1,'Шла','Саша'),
  (2,'ASDF','ZXCV'),(2,'QWER','QAZ')

SELECT * FROM Table1

-- Тестим UPDATE
UPDATE Table2
  SET Name += '_UPD', Explanation += '_UPD'
WHERE Name = 'ASDF'

SELECT * FROM Table1

-- Тестим DELETE
DELETE FROM Table2 WHERE Name = 'QWER'

SELECT * FROM Table1

GO
--Ну и вьюху можно сделать
CREATE VIEW V_Table1_V1 AS
SELECT T1.Id, 
  STUFF(
  (SELECT(
    SELECT CONCAT('; "',Name,'" : "',Explanation,'"') 
    FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.Id = T1.Id
    ORDER BY Name, Explanation FOR XML PATH('')
  )), 1, 2, '') AS CalcCommentV1
FROM Table1 T1
GO
SELECT * FROM V_Table1_V1
GO
--Так же если позволяет версия сервера, можно использовать STRING_AGG вместо FOR XML PATH для конкатенации строк
CREATE VIEW V_Table1_V2 AS
SELECT T1.Id, 
  --STRING_AGG можно использовать и в триггере
  STRING_AGG(CONCAT('"',Name,'" : "',Explanation,'"'), '; ') AS CalcCommentV2
FROM Table1 T1
  LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.Id = T2.Id
GROUP BY T1.Id
GO
SELECT * FROM V_Table1_V2
```

Результат работы триггера после вставки в Т2

| Id | Comment |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "Мама" : "Мыла"; "Раму" : "Рама"; "Шла" : "Саша" |
| 2 | "ASDF" : "ZXCV"; "QWER" : "QAZ" |

Результат триггера после обновления Т2

| Id | Comment |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "Мама" : "Мыла"; "Раму" : "Рама"; "Шла" : "Саша" |
| 2 | "ASDF_UPD" : "ZXCV_UPD"; "QWER" : "QAZ" |

Результат после удаления из Т2

| Id | Comment |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "Мама" : "Мыла"; "Раму" : "Рама"; "Шла" : "Саша" |
| 2 | "ASDF_UPD" : "ZXCV_UPD" |

Результат выгрузки данных из вьюхи с FOR XML PATH('')

| Id | CalcCommentV1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "Мама" : "Мыла"; "Раму" : "Рама"; "Шла" : "Саша" |
| 2 | "ASDF_UPD" : "ZXCV_UPD" |

Результат выгрузки данных из вьюхи с STRING_AGG

| Id | CalcCommentV2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "Мама" : "Мыла"; ; "Раму" : "Рама"; ; "Шла" : "Саша" |
| 2 | "ASDF_UPD" : "ZXCV_UPD" |

Если выбирать способ конкатенации строк - лучше конечно STRING_AGG - но вам надо проверить, поддерживает ли его ваша версия сервера